# I am getting "Segmentation Fault" dereferencing certain indices. How to fix it?

Tags: c++

Here is my code which is causing this error:

```
  int *marks[4];
  cout<<"\nPlease enter marks of PF: ";
  cin>>*marks[0];
  cout<<"\nPlease enter marks of LA: ";
  cin>>*marks[1];
  cout<<"\nPlease enter marks of CS: ";
  cin>>*marks[2];
  cout<<"\nPlease enter marks of Phy: ";
  cin>>*marks[3];
  cout<<"\nPlease enter marks of Prob: ";
  cin>>*marks[4];
```

I get this error after entering first two values for marks[0] & marks[1].

Comment: 1. You did not allocate memory for your integers. 2. *marks[4] is out of bounds. 3. Do you really need a dynamic array for this?

Comment: You should make that an answer

Comment: Nothing specific for any of all these removed tags now.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum For which question actually?

Answer (score 2):

If you're declaring

```
int *marks[4];
```

that doesn't mean there's an appropriate piece of memory allocated for the particular pointers in that array.

You have to allocate memory, before you could write there using a statement like

```
cin >> *marks[0];
```

Allocate memory like follows:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    marks[i] = new int();
}
```

before calling the `cin <<` operation.
And don't forget to deallocate, after it shouldn't be used any longer:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    delete marks[i];
}
```

---

The probably better solution would be to use a `std::array<int,[size compiletime determined]>` or a `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> marks;
```

Depending if you need a fixed size array, or a dynamically allocated array you can use either

```
const int fixed_array_size = 30;
std::array<int,fixed_array_size> marks;
```

---

```
size_t array_size = 0:
std::cin >> array_size;
std::vector<int> marks(array_size);
```